# Criteria parsing method

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I have this method, receive a list of integer, and must return an Collection of EmployeeComments, the problem is I don't know how take each result of the criteria and Add to the List of EmployeeComments:

```
        public ICollection<EmployeeComments> GetAllEmployeeCommentsByIdEmployee(List<int> idEmployeeList)
        {
            List<EmployeeComments> employeeCommentsList = new List<EmployeeComments>();

            using (ISession session = NHibernateSessionBuilder.OpenSession())
            {
                foreach (int idEmployee in idEmployeeList)
                {
                     employeeCommentsList = session
                                    .CreateCriteria(typeof(EmployeeComments))
                                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("IdEmployee", idEmployee)).List<EmployeeComments>();
                }

                return employeeCommentsList;
            }
        }
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should use Restrictions.In as follows:

```
public ICollection<EmployeeComments> GetAllEmployeeCommentsByIdEmployee(IEnumerable<int> idEmployeeList)
        {   
                    using (ISession session = NHibernateSessionBuilder.OpenSession())
                    {
                      return session
                              .CreateCriteria(typeof(EmployeeComments))
                              .Add(Restrictions.In(Projections.Id(), idEmployeeList.ToArray()))
                              .List<EmployeeComments>();

                    }
          }
```

Comment: the problem in your code is the IdEmployee is not the Primary Key, the IdEmployee is a ForeinKey, so, how can I modify you code for filter this column?. Thanks

Comment: Projections.Property("IdEmployee"), idEmployeeList.ToArray()). Thanks!!